# Where is the code file located in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to edit the website of done by my colleagues. Now I want to edit a js file or 
css file. But I cannot find out where the file is located in the the Wordpress. The code is as follows:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"    
media="screen">
```

So how can I find out the file main.css and try to edit it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you search the web? Something like [the doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) may prove useful to explain Wordpress internals.

Comment: You don't need the docs to find a file in your folder.

Comment: First of all, are you going to edit this file from WordPress's internal editor? or a text editor like sublime, or textmate etc? Because - those are 2 different sets of instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`template_url` will match the URL of the active theme's directory

If you're not using a child theme then follow this path:

```
your-project-folder/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/css/main.css
```

if you're using child theme then:

```
your-project-folder/wp-content/themes/your-child-theme-name/css/main.css
```

Comment: Basically, find the theme (in the folder where the WP install lives, on your computer) - and in there should be a `js` folder etc. WordPress uses a very specific stylesheet that is in the theme root called style.css --- many files may be compiled to this file, but you have to use this. Why your colleagues are pulling in a stylesheet like that - is a question to ask them. The correct way happens in the functions.php file (also found in the theme's folder) This link will explain the proper was to call styles and scripts: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: Thanks Felix and Sheriff. I finally find out the file